# How do I force the .NET XmlSerializer to include an xml:lang of en-US

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This should be pretty straightforward, I hope.  I am trying to set the "xml:lang" attribute of an XML element using XmlSerializer in .NET C#.  No matter what I do, I am not able to get the "xml:lang" to show up with a value of "en-US".

I'm fairly new to the XML Serialization but I've figured everything else out well enough.  This XML file will be used outside the US and it it's important that the language be defined.  Sample from my code is below.  This code gives me an error (I have defined the namespace elsewhere):

> "The global XML item 'lang' from namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' has mismatch default value
>   attributes: '' and 'en-US' and cannot be mapped to the same schema
>   item. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for
>   one of the items, or make sure that the default values match."

```
public class LongDescription
{

    [XmlAttribute("xml:lang", DataType = "language")]
    public string attrLang { get; set; }

    public LongDescription()
    {
        attrLang = "en-US";
    }
}
```

I found in the XmlSerializer documentation that "xml:lang" is a special case and must be set to "default" or "preserve".  If I use these values, it's populated but to the literal string "default" or "preserve" instead of the "en-US" I need.

I assume there is some special rules about xml:lang that I am missing but I haven't been able to find any documentation that tells me what I'm missing (even on StackOverflow).

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it an exception? If so, then show the full exception, including all InnerException - use `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: In the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), "Set this to 'default' or 'preserve'" applies to "xml:space (specifies how to handle white space)".   See [here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/).

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  I was able to use `XmlSerializer` to serialize your `LongDescription` class, and it works OK.

Comment: Well that is the innerException all the way down.  Honestly, guys, it's working now.  I have no idea what was wrong last night.  It had been a long day, I must have been doing something stupid.  Thanks for the help though.